How to portably write stdout as if piped through `less`?
I'm working on a Python project which is supposed to spit out output onto stdout. In some cases, the output can be quite long. In such situations, I'd like it if the output wasn't just dumped onto screen, but would behave as if piped into less, i.e. hold the position at the start of the output and allow me to scroll up and down with the arrow and j/k keys.
Is there a way of doing this without actually piping into less by e.g. calling subprocess? I suspect there might be a package which emulates this behaviour, but I wasn't able to find it. My project also needs to be able to run on Windows, so ideally the package would cover that for me.

This looks rather broad for a SO question. But you should think twice about your proposal. IMHO mimicking less is not that easy and require probably using a full screen library like curses. If you think you need that on Windows, it is probably worth a full project: a library module that would implement a TextWriter and provides a less behaviour. That way would allow a minimal coupling between your current project and this new one. Anyway as I have already said, this is way too broad for SO...

It looks like the Python standard library already has a solution for this, because help(...) already needs to invoke less or some equivalent.

... But before rolling your own, you should try a research on PyPI to see if someone has not already developped such a tool. Unfortunately we cannot help you with that either because asking for library or other off site resource is explicitely off topic. Maybe you should read [ask].
